# Why java doesn't give a bit read api?

Tags: java, byte, bit

I am using java ByteBuffer to save some basic data into streams. One situation is that I must transfer a "Boolean list" from one machine to another through the internet, so I want the buffer to be as small as possible.
I know the normal way of doing this is using buffer like this:

```java
    public final void writeBool(boolean b) throws IOException {
        writeByte(b ? 1 : 0);
    }
    public final void writeByte(int b) throws IOException {
        if (buffer.remaining() < Byte.BYTES) {
            flush();
        }
        buffer.put((byte) b);
    }


    public boolean readBool(long pos) {
        return readByte(pos) == 1;
    }

    public int readByte(long pos) {
        return buffer.get((int)pos) & 0xff;
    }
```

This is a way of converting a boolean into byte and store into buffer.
But I'm wandering, why not just putting a bit into buffer, so that a a byte can represent eight booleans, right?
The code maybe like this? But java doesn't have a `writeBit` function.

```java
    public final void writeBool(boolean b) throws IOException {
        // java doesn't have it.
        buffer.writeBit(b ? 0x1 : 0x0);
    }
    public final boolean readBool(long pos) throws IOException {
        // java doesn't have it
        return buffer.getBit(pos) == 0x01;
    }
```

So I think the only way doing that is "store eight booleans into a byte and write",like `((0x01f >>> 4) & 0x01) == 1` to check if the fifth boolean is true. But if I can get a byte, why not just let me get a bit?
Is there some other reason that java cannot let us operate bit?

Comment: Well, `ByteBuffer` addresses everything in whole bytes.

Comment: Yeah,, so I mean why not create a BitBuffer?

Comment: could you check: java.util.BitSet#toByteArray, java.util.BitSet#valueOf?

Comment: *So I think the only way doing that is "store eight booleans into a byte and write"...* What's going to happen if you have a list of *nine* booleans (or indeed *any* 'word-odd' length)?

Comment: Why care about how to implement with byte? just record a length of nine and write two bytes :) ? My point is why I cannot just save 9 bits rather than 16 bits ?

Comment: *My point is why I cannot just save 9 bits rather than 16 bits ?* How are you going to do that? How would the receiver know that it needs to inspect just nine bits of the sixteen (the granular minimum) it has just received?

Comment: why can't? just transfer a meta(int : 9) and data( 16bit, but 9 bit representing 9 booleans) . I only need 4 byte(meta) + 2 byte to save 9 booleans, rather than using 9 bytes( 9 boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yeah, so I mean why not create a `BitBuffer`?

That would be a question for the Java / OpenJDK development team, if you want a definitive answer.  However I *expect* they would make these points:

1. Such a class would have extremely limited utility in real applications.
2. Such a class is unnecessary given that an application doing (notionally) bit-oriented I/O can be implemented using `ByteBuffer` and a small amount of "bit-twiddling"
3. There is the technical issue that main-stream operating systems, and main-stream network protocols only support I/O down to the granularity of a byte<sup>1</sup>.  So, for example, file lengths are recorded in bytes, and creating a file containing precisely 42 bits of data (for example) is problematic.

Anyway, there is nothing stopping you from designing and writing your own `BitBuffer` class; e.g. as a wrapper for `ByteBuffer`.  And sharing it with other people who need such a thing.

Or looking on (say) Github for a Java class called `BitBuffer`.

---

<sup>1 - Indeed I don't know of *any* operating system, file system or network protocol that has a smaller granularity than this.</sup>

Comment: So I think maybe people just don't want us to directly operate 01 because that maybe much more complicate and unsafe.

Comment: Complicated ... and unnecessary.  The saving you get by bit-level packing is generally not worth the effort.

Comment: But *"people don't want us to"* is beside the point.  As I noted in my answer, there is nothing stopping you from implementing a `BitBuffer` API that does what >you< want to do.  Irrespective of what "people" think about the matter.